# AWS SSM & Patching Dependencies

Tags: amazon-web-services

Considering the use of the AWS SSM Agent in a Enterprise environment, does anyone know if patching dependencies are supported?

For example ensuring the Application tier is shutdown before patching the back-end and SQL Servers and reversing the startup process?

Granted in a stateless web only environment this is less of an issue but running Enterprise software means things are considerably more brittle.

Appreciate any information in this space.

Edit: Given the lack of response, how are others handling this scenario?